# Problem/Error with scraping in a pandas data frame with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm working on this csv (https://www.kaggle.com/jtrofe/beer-recipes) and I want to scrape every URL in data frame, but I can't because I have a problem/error, I'm not able to scrape all URL, if I try with 1 URL, it's ok and go, but with the function there is a problem... can someone help me?

This is my code:

```js
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep 


headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36'
}

base = 'https://www.brewersfriend.com'
links = [f'{base}{r}' for r in df['URL']]

while True:
    try:
        r = requests.get(links, headers=headers, stream=False, timeout=8).text
        break
    except:
        if r.status_code == 404:
            print("Client error")
            r.raise_for_status()
        sleep(1)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html5lib')

rating = soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'ratingValue'})

DEFAULT_VALUE = 'NaN'

if rating is None:
    rating = DEFAULT_VALUE
    
print(rating.text)
```

I'm already know that in some page there isn't a rating and so I create the DEFAULT_VALURE with Not a Number, but maybe is an error too.

Before this code there is the data frame, but I don't put it too.

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All kinds of messy things here. I won;t go over all of it, but one thing I see is you are trying to `print (rating.text)`. If youre rating is `'NaN'`, one error is that you can't do `rating.text`

This is not how I would write this up, but going off your initial coding:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep 


df = pd.read_csv('C:/recipeData/recipeData.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36'}
base = 'https://www.brewersfriend.com'

links = [f'{base}{r}' for r in df['URL']]
for link in links:
    try:
        r = requests.get(link, headers=headers, stream=False, timeout=8)

        if r.status_code == 404:
            print("Client error")
            r.raise_for_status()
            continue
        else:
            r = r.text     
    except:
        continue


    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html5lib')
    rating = soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'ratingValue'}).text
    DEFAULT_VALUE = 'NaN'

    if rating is None:
        rating = DEFAULT_VALUE

    print('%s: %s' %(link,rating))
```

Comment: there's some other issues with your code too. I'll break it down a little later today, just didn't have a lot of time yesterday to get into it all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do entire process

```
import requests, re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

p = re.compile(r'dataviewToken":"(.*?)"')
p1 = re.compile(r'"rowCount":(\d+)')
results = []
i = 0

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.kaggle.com/jtrofe/beer-recipes')   
    token = p.findall(r.text)[0]
    rows = int(p1.findall(r.text)[0])
    data = {"jwe":{"encryptedToken": token},"source":{"type":3,"dataset":{"url":"jtrofe/beer-recipes","tableType":1,"csv":{"fileName":"recipeData.csv","delimiter":",","headerRows":1}}},"select":["BeerID","Name","URL","Style","StyleID","Size(L)","OG","FG","ABV","IBU","Color","BoilSize","BoilTime","BoilGravity","Efficiency","MashThickness","SugarScale","BrewMethod","PitchRate","PrimaryTemp"],"skip":0,"take": rows}
    base = 'https://www.brewersfriend.com'
    r = s.post('https://www.kaggleusercontent.com/services/datasets/kaggle.dataview.v1.DataViewer/GetDataView', json = data).json()
    names, links = zip(*[(row['text'][1], base + row['text'][2]) for row in r['dataView']['rows']])

    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link, headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        if r.status_code == 403:
            rating = 'N/A'
        else:
            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
            rating = soup.select_one('[itemprop=ratingValue]')
            if rating is None:
                rating = 'N/A'
            else:
                rating = rating.text
        row = [names[i], rating]
        results.append(row)
        i+=1

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Name', 'Rating'])
print(df.head())
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```